# svnnotify html color diff

Tags: html, bash, svn, diff

I'm using `svnnotify` to send notification email upon commits. I have the following script on my repo's `hooks/post-commit`:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
for address in $(/bin/cat /var/svn/teachbyapp/hooks/addressee.list)
do
  /usr/local/bin/svnnotify \
    -r $REV \
    -C \
    -d \
    --diff-encoding utf8 \
    -H HTML::ColorDiff \
    -p $REPOS \
    -t "$address" \
    --from svn@factory.e-levelcom.com
done
```

It works but all I get is balck and white diff (no colors at all).
Added lines are underlined whereas removed lines have strike-through format. Nothing else, no color at all.
How can I get actually colored diff? Something like [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-diff-output-colorized-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it.

Thanks to [this](http://teguheko.echodess.com/2009/11/svn-notify-html-colordiff-inline-cs/) work

Also needed to append `--css-inline` option to `svnnotify` command in my script